# VFS not responding to email

Tags: paperwork, vfs-global

I have written an email to VFS Denmark regarding the name on my visa. They have an SLA of 2 days for responding to emails but have not responded even after 5 days. I have called them up multiple times and they assure of responding but don't respond.

There is no escalation option [on their website](http://dk.vfsglobal.co.in/faqs.html).

Are there any other options available?

Comment: VFS service standards are the worst. Try giving them a visit at the VFS centre where you deposited your application or the VFS centre nearest to you.

Comment: You're lucky you didn't get in touch with Italian embassy.

Comment: Terrible in the UK as well.  I have travelled a lot and obtained many visas over the years.  I don't remember one as hard as this.  It was a business visa but only a trip not a work permit; a tourist visa might have been a little easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually tried all the options possible (which are limited to emailing or calling, in this case?), I would try contacting the embassy of the visa you are applying for, since VFS is are supposed to be working through them anyway. It usually takes VFS little time to transfer the documents from the embassy to the VFS office, so knowing if the embassy's work is done and the visa is issued, you will know that the passport is coming, or you will at least be certain to blame the delay on VFS.

Comment: @alinamolina : Denmark embassy responded in 1 hour !! Thanks.